# Use model from the versioned app registry globally

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I'd like to run a custom command in my migration, that calls functions from other modules. These functions use some models, and as expected I ran into schema version mismatch (`OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'foo' in 'bar'")`.

If I were to use those models in the custom command I'd access the model with `apps.get_model('my_app', 'bar')`, but as those models are used in the external functions, I can't do that.

I'm sure, someone ran into this before although I couldn't find anything.

I was thinking about using the `unittest.mock.patch` decorator but it doesn't feel like the right solution.

I'm wondering if there's a more general solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

The versioned app registries are not globally accessible. You could pass the model as a parameter to the function, and use the current model as the default:

```
from my_app.models import Bar

def my_function(..., bar_model=Bar):
    # Use bar_model instead of Bar

# Your RunPython function
def migrate_something(apps, schema_editor):
    my_function(bar_model=apps.get_model('my_app', 'bar'))
```

You don't have to pass the `bar_model` parameter if you call it from regular code, but when calling it from a migration you can pass the historical model.

If you need multiple models you could pass `apps` instead:

```
from django.apps import apps as global_apps

def my_function(..., apps=global_apps):
    Bar = apps.get_model('my_app', 'bar')
```

Comment: That's the point: I'd like to avoid passing around the models as the external functions run in production and call further functions that operate with models and changing them seems error prone. I wanted to monkey patch them somehow, but as I see it's not possible, so I will add the functionality as a management command and run them manually